# How to append complex html blocks to a for loop

Tags: html, jquery

Im a bit new to handling json purely with jquery and html (used to work with django/python)

how would it be most elegant / clean way to append a complex html block like this?

```
               $.getJSON(url,function(data){
                 $.each(data, function(i, object){

                   $("#campaign_table tbody").append(
                       '<tr class="toggle">' +
                           '    <td>' + object.firstImpression + '</td>'  +
                           '    <td class="text-left">' + object.name + '</td>'  +
                           '    <td>' + object.impressions + '</td>'  +
                           '    <td>' + object.clicks + '</td>'  +
                           '    <td>' + object.clickRate + '</td>'  +
                           '    <td>' + object.sales + '</td>'  +
                           '    <td>' + object.salesRate + '</td>'  +
                         '</tr>'  +
                           '<tr class="tablesorter-childRow ">' +
                            '    <td></td>'  +
                            '    <td class="text-left"> Non targeted </td>'  +
                            '    <td>' + object.nonTargeted.impressions + '</td>'  +
                            '    <td>' + object.nonTargeted.clicks + '</td>'  +
                            '    <td>' + object.nonTargeted.clickRate + '</td>'  +
                            '    <td>' + object.nonTargeted.sales + '</td>'  +
                            '    <td>' + object.nonTargeted.salesRate + '</td>'  +
                          '</tr>'  +
                           '<tr class="tablesorter-childRow ">' +
                              '    <td></td>'  +
                              '    <td class="text-left"> Non targeted </td>'  +
                              '    <td>' + object.targeted.impressions + '</td>'  +
                              '    <td>' + object.targeted.clicks + '</td>'  +
                              '    <td>' + object.targeted.clickRate + '</td>'  +
                              '    <td>' + object.targeted.sales + '</td>'  +
                              '    <td>' + object.targeted.salesRate + '</td>'  +
                            '</tr>'
                   );

                 });
               });
```

Comment: There are different ways to do that, but I see nothing wrong with it.  Also, this question is much more suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Personally, I'd do the same. It's easy to read and modify in this format. Unless someone else can offer a reason not to do it like this, I'd say keep it like that.

Comment: I'd be tempted to make an `addRow()` function, but other than that I agree.  Sometimes readability is more important than streamlining code.

Comment: Got it... good to know i wasnt that much off then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is certainly viable, but you may want a separate function that loops over the specified object (e.g. one function you can use for `object`, `object.nonTargeted`, and `object.targeted`).

One concept that you may like that would help in this instance is JavaScript client side templates.  For example, using [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) you could have a template that looked like html:

```
<tr>
    <td>{{firstImpression}}</td>
    <!-- other cells -->
</tr>
```

and in JS:

```
$("#table").append(Handlebars.compile($("#template").html())(object));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5W4bx/

Comment: i looked at handlebars before posting this but the project deadline doesnt really allow me venture into unknown grounds :/ so i'l see what i can do with the object loops and i guess the rest of it should be allright then. thanks a lot for the feedback!